# Passato prossimo "continuo" in italiano

Tags: verbs, translation, tenses, past-tense

C'è un equivalente al "present perfect continuous" e al "past perfect continuous" dell'inglese?  Le traduzioni:

> I have been training a lot. --> Sono stato allenando molto.

> I had been reading for two hours before he interrupted me. --> Ero stato leggendo durante due ore prima lui m'interruppe.

Hanno senso grammaticale o pragmatico?

Answer (score 5):

No, purtroppo non hanno molto senso... A parte l'equivalenza con i tempi verbali di altre lingue o no, non sono proprio corrette.
La cosa più vicina potrebbe essere “Mi sono allenato molto [ultimamente / in questi mesi / etc.]” e “Stavo leggendo da due ore, quando lui mi interruppe”.

In generale, non c'è un'esatta corrispondenza fra i tempi verbali dell'inglese e quelli dell'italiano. Per esprimere i sensi che dici, nel primo caso puoi usare un passato prossimo (come nel mio esempio qui sopra) oppure un presente o una forma con il presente e il gerundio (“mi alleno / mi sto allenando”) per sottolineare che continui a fare quell'azione; nel secondo caso, un imperfetto, con o senza gerundio (“leggevo / stavo leggendo”).